# QSortFilterProxyModel Crash When Items Removed From QAbstractItemModel

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QTreeView with a custom QAbstractItemModel that handles adding/removing data.  I also have a custom QSortFilterProxyModel where I've implemented the filterAcceptsRow and filterAcceptsColumn functions.
The application will crash when attempting to remove items from the custom QAbstractItemModel ONLY if the user attempted a filter/search at some point before the back end changes the data.  See the following for the output when that happens:

> ASSERT: "source_item - delta_item_count >= 0" in file
> itemmodels\qsortfilterproxymodel.cpp, line 1092 Debug Error!
>
> Program: D:\path\to\lib\Qt5Cored.dll Module: 5.12.7 File:
> itemmodels\qsortfilterproxymodel.cpp Line: 1092
>
> ASSERT: "source_item - delta_item_count >= 0" in file
> itemmodels\qsortfilterproxymodel.cpp, line 1092

Originally I thought it was happening if a filtered/searched item was selected, but that is not the case, it just simply has to have attempted to a filter/search for the crash to occur.

Any ideas on what to check for in order to determine how to handle the issue before the crash?

Adding some code which unfortunately won't be helpful as the code that calls the functions isn't easily separated so that it will make sense out of context:

```
void VarModel::beginDeleteNodes(IVarNode* pParent, int firstRow, int lastRow)
{
    QModelIndex index = createIndex(static_cast<int>(pParent->getRow()), 0, pParent);
  
    beginRemoveRows(index, firstRow, lastRow);
}

void VarModel::endDeleteNodes()
{
    endRemoveRows();
}
```

Comment: This could be some inconsistency in the underlying model, add the code of the removal here, also https://wiki.qt.io/Model_Test might help

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  Model_Test did not show any failures.  A colleague suggested adding a boolean to check before making the begin/endRemoveRows function calls and the crash no longer happens.

Comment: boolean to check for what?

Comment: It ends up `if (!m_editing) { beginRemoveRows(...); m_editing = true; }` and `if (m_editing) { endRemoveRows(); m_editing = false;}`